# Selected 0 files but VBA Excel says I selected 1 file

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to run this script where I want a message box to state the number of open files I have selected. However, when I run the script iin VBA and click the cancel button in the file picker without having selected any files, the output of the message box states "You have selected 1 files" despite me having selected none. Could someone please help me with this?

```
Public OpenFiles As Variant
Public FileNumber As Integer
Public TextFile As Workbook
Public FileNumberString As String

Public Sub OpenFile()

    OpenFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File(s) to Import", MultiSelect:=True)
    FileNumber = Application.Count(OpenFiles)
    FileNumberString = FileNumber
    MsgBox ("You have selected " + FileNumberString + " Files")
End Sub
```

I am also scripting another property which only runs if FileNumber != 0. Hence, this is a problem for me:

```
Public Sub ImportTextFiles()

    Dim i As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If FileNumber = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("You did not select a file. Please select at least one file")

    Else:
        For i = 1 To FileNumber
            Set TextFile = Workbooks.Open(OpenFiles(i))
            TextFile.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
            Workbooks(1).Activate
            Workbooks(1).Worksheets.Add
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ActiveSheet.Name = TextFile.Name
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            TextFile.Close

        Next i

    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

***SOLUTIONS***

```
Public OpenFiles As Variant
Public FileNumber As Integer
Public TextFile As Workbook
Public FileNumberString As String

Public Function IsArrayAllocated(Arr As Variant) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
IsArrayAllocated = IsArray(Arr) And _
                    Not IsError(LBound(Arr, 1)) And _
                    LBound(Arr, 1) <= UBound(Arr, 1)
End Function
Public Sub OpenFile()
    OpenFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Text Files, *.txt", Title:="Select File(s) to Import", MultiSelect:=True)
    FileNumber = Application.CountA(OpenFiles)
    FileNumberString = CStr(FileNumber)
    MsgBox (IsArrayAllocated(OpenFiles))
    If IsArrayAllocated(OpenFiles) = False Then
        MsgBox ("You have selected 0 Files")
    Else:
        MsgBox ("You have selected " + FileNumberString + " Files")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `FileNumber = Application.Count(OpenFiles)` this can never be 0, as you have a file from which you run your script, which is open by definition.

Comment: I am also scripting another property which only runs if FileNumber is not 0. Hence, this is a problem for me

Comment: Well you could change that to `if  FileNumber > 1` but then you must make sure you close all other files from the start. Or have a look at some different approach, like in this tutorial: https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s209/multiselect.htm

Comment: I managed to solve it another way. Instead I conditioned for ElseIf OpenFiles = False, which meant if the user did not select any files. Thanks so much anyway! Let me know if you want the full code

Comment: SO wants to collect questions AND their answers, for future reference and for others to learn from. So posting your suggestion as an answer on your question is helpful.